# Change of variable in an ODE - requesting clarification on algebraic manipulation of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I would like to request an explanation to the solution to the following problem:

> Setting $x = e^t$, transform the ordinary differential equation 
>   $$  
>    x^2y^{\prime\prime} + xy^{\prime} + y=0
> $$

**Solution**

$$ 
  y^{\prime} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{dy}{dt}  \dfrac{dt}{dx}= \dfrac{ \dfrac{dy}{dt} }{ \dfrac{dx}{dt} } \tag{$\ast$}
$$

$$ 
  y^{\prime\prime} = \dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{dy}{dt} \dfrac{dt}{dx}\right)= \dfrac{ d^2 y }{dt^2} \left( \dfrac{dt}{dx} \right)^2 + \dfrac{dy}{dt} \dfrac{d^2 t}{dx^2} =\frac{ \dfrac{ d^2 y }{dt^2} \dfrac{dx}{dt} - \dfrac{dy}{dt} \dfrac{d^2 x}{dt^2} } {\left( \dfrac{dx}{dt} \right) ^3} \tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$

Next, we note that $x = e^t \implies x^{\prime}_t = x = x^{\prime\prime}_{tt} $

Thus
$$ 
  y^{\prime} = \dfrac{ \dfrac{dy}{dt} }{ x } \qquad y^{\prime\prime} = \frac{ \dfrac{ d^2 y }{dt^2} x - \dfrac{dy}{dt} x } {x^3} = \frac1{x^2} \left( \dfrac{ d^2 y }{dt^2} - \dfrac{dy}{dt}  \right)
$$

After substitution, we get the result 
$$ \dfrac{ d^2 y }{dt^2} + y = 0 $$

Now, when I worked it out alone, I was not able to reproduce the rightmost expression for the derivative given at $(\ast\ast)$. It seems to have been obtained by applying the quotient rule. More specifically, if I use the quotient rule on ($\ast$), I get a squared term in the denominator, as opposed to a cubed one. Also, the subtrahend I get is $\dfrac{d^2 x}{dxdt}$. After some algebraic manipulation attempts, I still cannot get the form in ($\ast\ast$). Thus, I'm requesting clarification on how this was obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the missing link in your Eq. (**)

$$y''=\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} \right)=\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} \right) \frac{dt}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt} \left ( \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} \right) \frac{dt}{dx}.$$ In the last part, the first $dx$ and the last $dt$ in the Denominator are interchangebale.